# Need help getting a Toast to appear on a Tab Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-toast

I'm trying to get a Toast to appear in a tabbed fragment when an EditText is left empty.

Here is my MainActivity's onCreate:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);        
    }
}
```

My Tabbed Fragment works fine with this code:

```
public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work when creating the Toast like this:

```
public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText textFillCheck;
    Button submitCheck;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        submitCheck = (Button) submitCheck.findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);
        textFillCheck = (EditText) textFillCheck.findViewById(R.id.signupFirstName);
        submitCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textFillCheck.getText().toString())) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignupFragment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textFillCheck.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the views of your Fragment's layout so the layout you're returning in `onCreateView()` doesn't have your logic attached to it. You should set up your Fragment to look something like this:

```
public class SignupFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText textFillCheck;
    Button submitCheck;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

        // Store a reference to your Fragment's inflated layout
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signup, container, false);
        
        // Use the reference to access your Fragment's views
        submitCheck = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);
        textFillCheck = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.signupFirstName);
        
        submitCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textFillCheck.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textFillCheck.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Return the inflated layout
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it's running in-part with this fix, the 'else' statement returns fine when the EditText is filled but the app closes when the field is empty and the Button clicked

Comment: I just noticed that the Intent isn't correct. What is the desired behavior if the EditText is empty? Do you want to just show the Toast or do you want to additionally navigate to another activity?

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the Intent and all is working.

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to reflect the removed Intent. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I am amazed why your code is not having any error like **`VIEW DOES NOT EXIST`** or **`NULL POINTER EXCEPTION`** because

First, you change the activity before showing the Toast secondly you are inflating the layout after the initialization of views and not getting the context properly, Right way of doing what you are trying to achieve is using **`OnViewCreated()`** like this

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    submitCheck = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);

    textFillCheck = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.signupFirstName);

    submitCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textFillCheck.getText().toString())) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please fill in all fields", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignupFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else{
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), textFillCheck.getText().toString(), 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
  }
```

Comment: App now starts but doesn't show the fragments layout components.

Comment: that's because you are just making the intent and starting the activity